# A method Bar in class Foo logs a message with debug method. How to write testcode for method Bar

Tags: php, phpunit

My class Foo has a method called Bar which is when called logs a debug message. Class Foo gets \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger in its __contruct method. I'v created a testBar method in my FooTest Class but debug method in my Bar method is giving following error

> PHP Fatal error:  Class Mock_LoggerInterface_a49cf619 contains 8 abstract >methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining >methods (Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::emergency, Psr\Log>\LoggerInterface::alert, Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::critical, ...) in /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects>/src/Generator.php(264) : eval()'d code on line 1

My class code is given below

```
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Foo {


    private $logger;
    private $myclassObject;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
    public function Bar ()
    {
      // some code
      $logger->debug ('debug message')

    }
}
```

My test class given below

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class FooTest extends TestCase
{

    private $logger;
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->logger = $this->getMockBuilder('\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')
            ->setMethods(null)
            ->getMock();

        $this->logger->expects($this->any())
            ->method('debug')
            ->willReturn('Message Logged');
    }

    $this->myclassObject = $this->getMockBuilder('MyVendor\MyModule\Model\Foo')
    ->setMethods(['__construct'])        
    ->setConstructorArgs(['$logger'])
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->getMock();

    public function testBar()
    {

        $this->assertEquals($expected_result,$this->myclassObject->Bar());
    }
}
```

I'm expecting to see a Successful unit test with stubbed debug method logging  'Message Logged'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm ignoring the syntax issue with defining `$this->myclassObject` at the class level, because I assume that's a typo from you creating this question.

I *think* that you have two problems:

- You're overriding PHPUnit's ability to mock a class/interface's abstract/interface methods by specifying `null` in LoggerInterface's setMethods, which tells it not to mock anything
- You're both disabling the Foo constructor *and* providing constructor args (in quotes as a scalar value of the variable name)

You also are referencing `$logger` which doesn't exist.

I'd also suggest that in your example, you don't need to partially mock Foo at all, since you're not mocking any of its functionality at this point. You can simply call `new Foo($this->logger)`. I assume, however, that your example is cut down and you *do* need to partially mock other parts of the class, so will leave it for now.

Try this:

```php
class FooTest extends TestCase
{
    private $logger;
    private $myclassObject;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->logger = $this->createMock('\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface');

        $this->logger->expects($this->any())
            ->method('debug')
            ->willReturn('Message Logged');

        $this->myclassObject = $this->getMockBuilder('\MyVendor\MyModule\Model\Foo')
            ->setConstructorArgs([$this->logger])
            ->getMock();
    }

    public function testBar()
    {
        $this->assertEquals($expected_result, $this->myclassObject->Bar());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the myclassObject correction. In my view I think disableOriginalConstructor needs to be used in Foo Mock since we are stubbing logger debug method. Also where would this 'Message Logged' will be saved. I cant find it in debug.log Should it be saved here.

Comment: You’re mocking the logger so it won’t log anywhere. You can run assertions that it gets called on your mock instead